# All elements of an array being updated instead of just one

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's an online example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xwsuee2j/1/

I am showing multiple data grids on a page. These data grids are produced using JavaScript objects. The only difference between these objects are one field so here's what I've done to save huge amounts of space/code.

Set the array object:

```
var dxDataGrids = [];
```

Create the standard object:

```
var BM_DataGrid = {
    showColumnLines: true,
    showRowLines: true,
    filterRow: {
        visible: true
    },
    searchPanel: {
        visible: true,
        width: 240,
        placeholder: 'Filter Search'
    },
    height: 'calc(100% - 54px)',
    columnAutoWidth: true,
    scrolling: {
        mode: 'standard',
        preloadEnabled: true
    },
    allowColumnResizing: true
};
```

Some dummy data sources:

```
var dataSource1 = [{
    RouteName: 'LE01',
    EmployeeRef: 'DRIVER1',
    VehicleRef: 'VEHICLE1',
    Difference: 0
}, {
    RouteName: 'LE02',
    EmployeeRef: 'DRIVER2',
    VehicleRef: 'VEHICLE2',
    Difference: 0
}, {
    RouteName: 'LE03',
    EmployeeRef: 'DRIVER3',
    VehicleRef: 'VEHICLE3',
    Difference: 0
}];
var dataSource2 = [{
    RouteName: 'LE04',
    EmployeeRef: 'DRIVER4',
    VehicleRef: 'VEHICLE4',
    Difference: 0
}, {
    RouteName: 'LE05',
    EmployeeRef: 'DRIVER5',
    VehicleRef: 'VEHICLE5',
    Difference: 0
}, {
    RouteName: 'LE06',
    EmployeeRef: 'DRIVER6',
    VehicleRef: 'VEHICLE6',
    Difference: 0
}];
```

And the bit that spits out my data:

```
dxDataGrids['Grid1'] = BM_DataGrid;
dxDataGrids['Grid2'] = BM_DataGrid;
dxDataGrids['Grid1'].dataSource = dataSource1; // Set DataSource 1
console.log(dxDataGrids['Grid1'].dataSource); // Write out field for 'Grid1' (CORRECT)
dxDataGrids['Grid2'].dataSource = dataSource2; // Set DataSource 2
console.log(dxDataGrids['Grid2'].dataSource); // Write out field for 'Grid2' (CORRECT)
console.log(dxDataGrids['Grid1'].dataSource); // Write out field for 'Grid1' (INCORRECT)
```

Basically I would like to know why updating one of the object arrays, it updates all of them?

Comment: What's `BM_DataGrid`? Pretty sure you need to copy/duplicate it, so that copies can be changed independently of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anders has answered perfectly why this happens, I will try to help you solve the problem. Instead of creating *one* data grid and reference to it multiple times, you should create *multiple* data grids, one for each reference.

```
function get_std_BM_DataGrid() {
    var dg = {
        showColumnLines: true,
        showRowLines: true,
        filterRow: {
            visible: true
        },
        searchPanel: {
            visible: true,
            width: 240,
            placeholder: 'Filter Search'
        },
        height: 'calc(100% - 54px)',
        columnAutoWidth: true,
        scrolling: {
            mode: 'standard',
            preloadEnabled: true
        },
        allowColumnResizing: true
    };
    return dg;
}
```

Then simply do something like `dxDataGrids['Grid1'] = get_std_BM_DataGrid();`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just give it a whirl.

Answer (score 7):

You have

```
dxDataGrids['Grid1'] = BM_DataGrid;
dxDataGrids['Grid2'] = BM_DataGrid;
```

so essentially both your array elements point to the *same object*.

Then when setting

```
dxDataGrids['Grid1'].dataSource = dataSource1;
```

you're setting the `datasource` on the `BM_DataGrid` object, which incidentally is the same `datasource` attribute on

```
dxDataGrids['Grid2'].dataSource = dataSource2;
```

since both array elements are the same object, remember? Thus, the "last" `dataSource` assignment "wins", which is exactly what you see.

Makes sense?

Cheers,

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but why does it just make a reference instead of setting a value?

Comment: @JamieBarker: because reference **is** the value here.

Comment: How do you make Grid1 and Grid2 two separate entities then?

Comment: So if I did `var test1 = BM_DataGrid, test2 = BM_DataGrid;` and then updated `test2`, it would also update `test1`?

Comment: Gotcha. I'm going to accept Betamos' answer because it helped solve my problem, but because this answer answered my question I'll give @AndersR.Bystrup some rep. by other means :)